# Is there a way to force Conda to install packages that are compatible with a specific version of GLIBC?

Tags: python, machine-learning, conda, glibc, rhel6

I have a legacy RHEL6 machine that I cannot upgrade or make any changes to existing libraries on. So far I have been unsuccessful in getting a working conda environment due to GLIBC incompatibilities. Is the any way to force Conda to install packages that are compatible with a specific version of GLIBC? I know I can force versions of python, tensorflow, etc. but so far I have not found a working combination and I would like to avoid manually testing package combinations.